# Prove the difference of two independent, recurrent and identical random walks is a recurrent random walk

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process, random-walk

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent recurrent random walks with the same transition matrix $p$ on $\mathcal{Z}$.

**Is $Z:=X-Y$ a recurrent random walk?**

I would like to prove it by using this result (Theorem 17.41 of Probability Theory by A. Klenke, 3rd version):

> A random walk on $\mathcal{Z}$ with $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}|x|p(0,x)$ is recurrent if and only if $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}xp(0,x)=0$.

**My attempt**

For starting points $x,y\in\mathcal{Z}$ of $X$ and $Y$, $z=x-y$ and
$$
\bar p(z,z_1)=P_z[Z_1=z_1]=P_{x,y}[X_1-Y_1=z_1]=\sum_{y_1=-\infty}^{\infty}P_x[X_1=z_1+y_1|Y_1=y_1]P_y[Y_1=y_1]=
\\\sum_{y_1=-\infty}^{\infty}p(x,z_1+y_1)p(y,y_1)
$$

Then
$$
\sum_{z_1=-\infty}^{\infty}z_1\bar p(z,z_1)=\sum_{x_1=-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{y_1=-\infty}^{\infty}(x_1-y_1)p(x,z_1+y_1)p(y,y_1)
\\
\sum_{y_1=-\infty}^{\infty}p(y,y_1)\sum_{x_1=-\infty}^{\infty}x_1p(x,x_1)-\sum_{x_1=-\infty}^{\infty}p(x,x_1)\sum_{y_1=-\infty}^{\infty}y_1p(y,y_1)
\\
\sum_{y_1=-\infty}^{\infty}p(y,y_1)\sum_{s=-\infty}^{\infty}(x+s)p(0,s)-\sum_{x_1=-\infty}^{\infty}p(x,x_1)\sum_{t_1=-\infty}^{\infty}(y+t)p(0,t)
\\=x-y=z
$$

**Question**
How can I conclude from here? Is it sufficient to take $z=0$ and apply the theorem above? How can I see that $Z$ is indeed a random walk?

Please, let me know if more details are needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to prove that: (i) $Z$ is a random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$ itself, (ii) that $\sum_z|z|p_Z(0,z)<\infty$ and, (iii) to conlude, that $\sum_zzp_Z(0,z)=0$.

We may write $Z_n=(x-y)+\sum_{k\leq n}(\xi_k^X-\xi_k^Y)$ where $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ are the initial states of $X,Y$ respectively and $(\xi^X_n)_n,(\xi^Y_n)_n$ are the IID increments of $X$ and $Y$ respectively. Write $z=x-y,\xi^Z_k=\xi^X_k-\xi^Y_k$ and note $(\xi^Z_n)_n$ are IID. So we have that $Z$ is a random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$ i.e. $Z_n=z+\sum_{k\leq n}\xi^Z_k$. We have $E[|Z_1-z|]\leq E[|\xi_1^X|]+E[|\xi_1^Y|]=\sum_x|x|p_X(0,x)+\sum_y|y|p_Y(0,y)<\infty$. Now, since $X,Y$ are recurrent, $\sum_zzp_Z(0,z)=E[Z_1-z]=E[\xi^X_1]-E[\xi_1^Y]=\sum_xx p_X(0,x)+\sum_yyp_Y(0,y)=0$.

Comment: Thanks: you also checked that the conditions hold for the theorem to be applied. Just to have an idea, how far are my computations from yours, especially from your last one about $E[|Z_1-z|]$?

Comment: You seem to have showed that $E[Z_1]=z$, but you may need to check all the conditions for the theorem to hold first.

Comment: That's right. I was trying to check them from the last result but as you showed it is easier to see them directly by expressing $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ as sum of iid rvs.